Matrix decomposition $u_1v_1^\intercal+u_2v_2^\intercal$
I have a matrix $A$ and $B$ of shapes $3 \times 4$ and $2 \times 3$ respectively. I need to write them of the form $u_1v_1^\intercal+u_2v_2^\intercal$. I am not sure how to perform this decomposition. Should I do factorization or any standard form of transformation? Please advise how to approach this problem. Trying to do this by hand.
A = [[1,2,1,1],
[2,2,2,2],
[1,2,1,1]]

This is possible if and only if the matrices have rank at most $2$. The standard way to do this is using singular value decomposition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is unreadable. Please format your formulas.

@Pranay: I was thinking if there is an any way to represent using the column or row space of the matrix

The row and column spaces are precisely what the two unitary matrices in the SVD capture. See this section in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Separable_models

@eashwarnatarajan Please provide more context for your question. Are you trying to write a program that does this, or are you trying to do this by hand? Are there specific matrices $A$ and $B$ that you have in mind, or is this a general procedure that you're looking for? Do we have any guarantee regarding the rank of $A$? If not, then such a decomposition might be impossible. Would you want an expression $u_1v_1^T + u_2v_2^T$ that approximates $A$ in this case?

Hi @BenGrossmann, I am trying to do this by hand. I have a matrix A = [[1,2,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[1,2,1,1]]

First of all, note that the decomposition you're looking for is equivalent to a rank factorization. In particular, suppose that $C$ and $F$ are matrices of sizes $3 \times 2$ and $2 \times 4$ respectively such that $A = CF$. If $u_1,u_2$ are the columns of $C$ and $v_1,v_2$ are the columns of $F^T$, then we can see with block-matrix multiplication that
$$
A = CF = \pmatrix{u_1 & u_2}\pmatrix{v_1^T\\
v_2^T} = u_1v_1^T + u_2v_2^T.
$$
Similarly, this process could be reversed to construct $C$ and $F$ from $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$.
For a general, by-hand approach to rank factorization, I would recommend the row-echelon form based approach from the first linked Wikipedia page. For computational approaches, it is common to use a "thin" or "reduced" QR decomposition or a compact singular value decomposition.
In this case, however, there is a nice and intuitive approach that we can take advantage of the fact that $A$ has repeated columns. We have
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1}.
$$
If we take $C$ to be the matrix that "lists" the distinct columns and $F$ to be a matrix that selects the column from $C$ corresponding to each column of $A$, then we have
$$
C = \pmatrix{1 & 2\\2&2\\1&2}, \quad F = 
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0&1&0&0}.
$$
Verify that $A = CF$. With the block-matrix multiplication trick described above, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\2\\1}\pmatrix{1&0&1&1} + \pmatrix{2\\2\\2}\pmatrix{0&1&0&0}.
$$
Interestingly, this is the same decomposition that you would get using the row-echelon form based approach.
As an alternative, you can use the rows of $A$ to build the matrix $F$ and similarly take advantage of the fact that $A$ has repeating rows. Doing so gives you
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\1&0}, \quad F = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 1 & 1\\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2}.
$$

Incidentally, this process is very easy for $B$. Taking $I_2$ to denote the size-2 identity matrix, we have
$$
B = I_2B = 
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\
0&1}
\pmatrix{
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}
} = \\
\pmatrix{1\\0}\pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}} + 
\pmatrix{0\\1}\pmatrix{b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}}.
$$
You could also decompose the product $BI_3$ for another result.
